# order by count when you have to count only certain items

Tags: sql, mysql

I have this query:

```
SELECT tips.* 
FROM   `tips` `t` 
       LEFT JOIN tip_usage 
         ON tip_usage.tip_id = t.id 
GROUP  BY t.id 
ORDER  BY COUNT(CASE 
                  WHEN status = 'Active' THEN status 
                  ELSE NULL 
                END) DESC
```

As you see here, I use a left join and I count only the records which are `Active`

Can I make this query to be different, and to lose the case stuff from the count?

Comment: Which table does the column "status" belong to?

Comment: Where reduces the amount of records returned. `status` belongs to `tip_usage` I want to sort by number of Active records aka as popularity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to return all tips, regardless of status, and but sort by number of Active records, then this is as pretty as you are going to get.

If you only want to return active tips, then you can add `Where status = 'Active'` and then just order by Count(t.id) desc.

One alternative is that you have a NumActive int column in the tips table, and you keep this update whenever a new tip_usage record is added or modified for a given tip. This puts more overhead into the insert/delete/update operations for tip_usage, but would make this query much simpler:

```
select *
from tips
Order by tips.NumActive desc
```

Another alternative is:

```
Select tips.*
From tips
Order by (
  Select count(tip_id) 
  From tips_usage as t 
  Where t.tip_id = tips.id and status = 'Active') DESC
```

Though this exchanges a case for a subquery, so just complex in a different way.

Answer (score 1):

Quick note, you cannot select t.* and group on t.id.  So with that being said:

```
SELECT t.id,coalesce(tu.cntUsed,0) as cntUsed
  FROM   `tips` `t` 
  LEFT 
  JOIN (Select tip_id,count(*) as cntUsed
          from tip_usage
         WHERE status='Active'
         group by tip_id
       ) tu
    ON t.id = tu.tip_id
 ORDER coalesce(tu.cntUsed,0)
```

Since you want to left-join and include the tips that have no usage, this at least sorts them all at the top with a value of zero, which is the most accurate statement of the reality of what is in the tables.

Comment: Why did you told me: Quick note, you cannot select t.* and group on t.id? My query above works ok.

Comment: Hmmm, mySQL may be doing you a favor here, I'm not a mySQL expert so I can't say.  But the idea is this, imagine you have three columns with values {1,a,b} and {1,x,y} an you group on the first column and ask for select *.  Should it return {1,a,b} or {1,x,y}?  how does it know?  Perhaps mySQL allows it because it knows id is unique?

Comment: I have found that MySQL doesn't adhere to the standards in using GROUP BY clause...things like shown above work when you think they shouldn't....and I personally think MySQL shouldn't "help" because you get people posting SQL like above that the rest of us look at and go, "That shouldn't work!" but it does!

Comment: @leslie, I got my start on Foxpro which would "help" us that way, and when I learned real SQL I had some adjusting to do.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT tips.*, COUNT(*) AS number
FROM tip_usage
LEFT JOIN tips ON tips.id = tip_id
WHERE STATUS = "Active"
GROUP BY tip_id
ORDER BY number DESC
```